# Why is typeof an operator instead of a property?

Tags: javascript, typeof

I'm learning Javascript and I ran across something that feels kind of "quirky".

Why isn't typeof a property like `.length` or `.name`?  It seems like it should be in that category.  Instead it's considered an operator sort of like an equals sign `=`

Maybe there is an obvious explanation or I'm not understanding something (easily possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 9):

If it was a property, then you wouldn't be able to test if something was `undefined` since undefined values can't have properties.

Worse, if a variable was undeclared, then trying to test a property on it would throw a ReferenceError.

Comment: Ok thanks a ton that makes sense!  I'll remember that.

Answer (score 2):

Since `typeof` is universal in JavaScript (that is, you can use it against any variable), it could have been implemented as a property on Object. But, if it were, you wouldn't be able to call it on `null` and `undefined` types.

```
if(someNullVariable.typeof . . .) { . . . } // error
```

But, because it is an operator, you can use it independent of what you are checking:

```
if(typeof someNullVariable === "null")  { . . . }  // Match!
```

Comment: Ok I see, it makes it more useful in practice.  Thanks!